# is it possible Java/JERSY with JPA without spring boot

Tags: java, jpa, jersey, rest

Is it possible develop Java application using JERSY + JPA only without spring boot ,
i got an error while building connection , search entire internet wanted to build a CRUD example with using JERSY and JPA without any other framework like Spring Boot.
i am sorry if am using wrong approach for it.

Comment: You need a framework. JPA is "only" a specification (a set of interfaces, if you will). It is the framework's responsibility to supply implementations that conform to the interface specification.

Comment: @Turing85 Thank you for quick comment ,  i would like to use JERSY as framework with JPA , i am new to JAVA .. if that possible please help me in this to get example of CRUD.

Comment: Writing a crud rest service as a beginner may be a bit overwhelming. I suggest starting on a smaller scale, with some basics. I will not write a Crud repository for you, sorry. That is out-of-scope for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Turing85 NP i was actually was just wondering just looking internet they all related with spring boot , sorry for asking CRUD example , i just wanted know possible or not. Thanks Man.

Answer (score -1):

Finally My problem has been solved , I missed one dependency.